# To show a function differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed vector and $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a linear transformation . Define $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = \langle A,T(x)\rangle$$  where the brackets refer to standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Show that $f$ is differentiable and identify the derivative . Compute $D^2 f(x)$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in the manner appropriate for assigning homework.

Comment: This is not a homework question and i seem to have not understood this question at all. SO I couldn't even approach it. Please help with phrasing the question as well as the solution.

Comment: CAn someone help me understand the question ? and also the approach towards the solution ? Thanks

Comment: Do you know what it means to say that a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable?